# Changing WSO2_CARBON_DB from H2 to MySql

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

In WSO2 API Manager 3.0.0, changing from embedded H2 Database to Mysql documentation state about changing of the following databases: WSO2_SHARED_DB, WSO2AM_DB, WSO2_MB_STORE_DB irrespective deployment option (Single Node or Active-Active). But it is required to change the WSO2_CARBON_DB default database H2 to MySql? If yes, then please direct to towards the steps required to change it to MySql from H2 in WSO2 API manager 3.0.0
Ref URL: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/InstallAndSetup/SettingUpDatabases/ChangingDefaultDatabases/changing-to-mysql

Answer (score 0):

When setting up the environment, you only need to move WSO2_SHARED_DB and  WSO2AM_DB H2 databases to MySql. WSO2_CARBON_DB and MB_Store_DB can be kept as H2 database. You can refer [1] for configuring deployment.toml for Mysql.

[1] - 
https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/blob/master/docker-compose/apim-with-analytics/apim/config/repository/conf/deployment.toml#L19

Comment: what data is stored in WSO2_CARBON_DB and do those data play any key role during backup and restore?

Comment: The data that is stored in this database is recoverable.